# I need to use one href anchor for 2 actions

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, anchor, href

I may be asking this incorrectly. I'm not super familiar with the terminology of javascript or ajax.  I've been able to get by just enough using html and javascript code from highslidejs to create most of our companies in-house web pages. Now I am stuck on how to go about this issue.  Originally I built this page using simply html code.  Then one of the higher ups requested that I use this template. :( So I am attempting to work with this template that has no functionality what so ever.  Everything was going ok until I came to having to reveal the video content below each selection using the ajax code that I grabbed from hsjs. While I got it to show the videos onclick with each submenu item.. the problem is that the way the template is built it has each video positioned just under it's name when it is clicked. And it doesn't clear the previous video being played. I was thinking that I could have each video be targeted to play in a specific div with an iframe. That way each video will play in that same div and override the previous one selected thereby avoiding having several open at the same time.   I have had that work before.  However, I am running into a conflict with the href  having two functions: "javascript:;" and "mymoviesource.mp4"
I apologize for the lengthy explanation of my problem.  Here is my work in progress:  http://www.foxsportsgraphics.com/Lab-presentation/index-6-7a.html
I'm currently only working with the first "Virtual Reality" menu tab.  I had each movie opening in a separate web window but they would like for each to open as the first one does for "Big East Basketball (jeep)" in that same position.  Here is my first web page that I used a target iframe to play each video in:
http://www.foxsportsgraphics.com/template/index-Lab-original.html  It works great having each video play in the same spot.  But I don't know how to have one href do both: javascript code to reveal the iframe below the selections and target the video URL's to play in the iframe .  Would it be better to use an "onclick" behavior to reveal the iframe?  And if so.. how would i get the positions of the iframe to be in the same place for each selection?  Again, I apologize if this question is troublesome because of my lack of knowledge in this area.  But I would so greatly appreciate any help at all to direct me in some way to be able to accomplish what I want to do.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: `[TIP]` Since human beings are reading your question, try to be concise and format nicely. The difference between someone helping you or not, is a difference of whether they care to read it. Try to rewrite your question. You can also add a TLDR; as well.

Comment: Paragraphs and code tags please.  But to answer one bit that stood out: yes onlcick would let you call a JavaScript function that does more than one thing.

Comment: This is the code that I used for the 1st web page that I created with javascript that drops down the menu list items and then has each video link targeted to open in a specific "animations" div:

Comment: <a href="javascript:;" onclick="var r=document.getElementById('vr').style;r.display=(r.display=='none')?'':'none';this.innerTEXT=(r.display=='none')?'&lt;B&gt;vr&lt;/B&gt;':'&lt;B&gt;vr&lt;/B&gt;';try {hs.getExpander(this).reflow();} catch(e){}; return false;MM_showHideLayers('animations','','hide')">

Comment: <div id="vr" style="display:none">

   <ul>
   <li class="list">
   <div class="border"><a href="clips/new/JEEP-VR_BIGEAST-SEMIS_3-10.mp4" target="animations" onclick="closeNav();MM_showHideLayers('animations','','show')">&nbsp;&nbsp;BIG EAST BASKETBALL (JEEP)</a></div></li>

Comment: With the template that I was asked to use I do not know how to have the video links all open in the same location on the screen such as a target div since my href anchor is activating the javascript that reveals the content below the list item.  I need it to also to direct the video link for that list item to open in a specified div "onclick"